# Back transformation of log10 transformed data in SPSS

Tags: anova, logarithm, back-transformation

I have transformed my quantitative variable by using the `log10` function in order to run some parametric tests (ANOVA) but when I want to make pairwise comparisons of the mean effects should I use some back transformation functions? For example I can use the reverse function by taking 10 to the power of the transformed variable values but in this case I receive a variable which is totally the same as the original data (before the first transformation). So I am wondering if it is OK for the pairwise comparisons to use the original data (without any transformations) or I should use some more sophisticated back transformation technique / function.

For me it does not make much sense to transform once and after that when I apply a back transformation to have absolutely the same result (i.e., the original data)? This seems like some kind of contradiction because on the one hand, we transform the data but when we cannot use it we just use the original data.

Comment: Was there any reason why you transformed the data in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

You presumably log-transformed your data for ANOVA because residuals weren't normally distributed and/or they depended on the magnitudes of the data values. So, for the same reasons, further statistical tests (like pairwise comparisons) should also be performed on the transformed data.

When you write up your results you might back-transform to the original scale to make results easier for a reader who expects to see values in that scale, but note that confidence intervals on the original scale will no longer be symmetric about the mean values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response!!! So you suggest me continue using the transformed variable even for the pairwise analyses? But may be in this case I should interprete only the P vales (Sig.) i.e. if the effects are significant but not the exact values given in the table about the Mean differences?

P.S. The condition of equality of variences was violated, that is why I used to the lg10 transformation

Comment: Yes. Do _all_ of your statistical analyses (including pairwise analyses) in the log-transformed scale, because you presumably want equality of variances for the pairwise tests too. If your readers are expecting data in the original scale, then transform back to that scale for display purposes only. Make what you did clear when describing the methods in your report or publication.

Comment: Perfect!! But what do you mean by transforming back to the scale for display purposes? It means that I can use the original data before the transformations or I should make a second transformation of the already transformed variable but this time backwords transformation?

Comment: if you're reporting individual values, both methods ive the same result, as you note. If you want to report mean values and confidence limits in the original scale, take the means and the confidence limits in the transformed scale and back transform them to the original scale when you construct your summary tables.

Comment: You also said earlier that "confidence intervals on the original scale will no longer be symmetric about the mean values" if I use the orgonal data but:  when I run the pairwise comparisons as you suggested (with the transformed variable) since I am using Bonferroni test do I have the right to interprete the 95% Confidence Interval for Differences (Lower & Upper Bound) ??? Probably not!

Comment: You do all the statistical interpretation, including confidence intervals for differences, in the log-transformed scale. For differences it might be simpler to present all your results in the log-transformed scale. Note that a difference in the log scale is equivalent to a ratio in the original scale. So in the original scale you might present the summaries in terms of ratios.

Comment: Can you suggest me anyway some back transformations that will make my data close to the original so that I can interprete everything in Pairwise comparison or at least a book on this topic?

Comment: aha, ok thank you very much I have not seen your post when I wrote my last one! Can you just give me an example what you mean by "the original scale you might present the summaries in terms of ratios". How can I do it?

Comment: As an extreme example, say for variable A you have values of 1, 3,10,30; for variable B values are 2,6,20,60. Instead of presenting the difference between mean(log10(B)) and mean(log10(A)), you back transform that difference to get a value of 2, an estimate of the ratio of B/A.

Comment: I am sorry I should have been more precise. In my case I have 3 categorical variables (factors) and 1 continuous variable (result for which I applied a lg10 transformation to meet the assumption of equality of variances)........so in my case I have only one log10 variable......How should I make the ratio in this case?

Comment: Am I correct that the continuous log-transformed variable is the dependent variable in your analysis, and you have 3 separate categorical variables as independent factor variables? How many levels does each of the factor variables have? Which specific pairwise comparisons do you wish to make?

Comment: Yes, that is right! Each factor has 2 levels. I was thinking to do the three possible pairwise comparisons : by using as a comparing variable the 1st factor, after that the secod one, and after that the third one.